# How ResponseListener works in snmp4j

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, snmp, snmp4j

I have written a simple program to understand how snmp4j asynchronous request/response works:

```
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
transport.listen();

Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse("udp:192.168.1.116/161");
CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
target.setAddress(targetAddress);
target.setCommunity(new OctetString("nid"));
target.setRetries(0);
target.setTimeout(30000);
target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);

ResponseListener listener = new ResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(ResponseEvent event) {
        ((Snmp) event.getSource()).cancel(event.getRequest(), this);
        System.out.println("Received response PDU is: " + event.getResponse());
        System.out.println("response listener thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("**********************************");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
};

System.out.println("main thread id: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    PDU pdu1 = new PDU();
    pdu1.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1")));
    pdu1.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2")));
    pdu1.setType(PDU.GET);
    snmp.send(pdu1, target, null, listener);
}

Thread.sleep(100000);
```

sample output is like this:

```
main thread id: 1
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585942, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585943, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585944, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585945, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585946, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585947, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
Received response PDU is: null
response listener thread id: 9
**********************************
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585948, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
Received response PDU is: null
response listener thread id: 9
**********************************
Received response PDU is: RESPONSE[requestID=205585950, errorStatus=Success(0), errorIndex=0, VBS[1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.1 = 1; 1.3.6.1.4.1.22420.2.5.3.1.1.2 = 2]]
response listener thread id: 8
**********************************
```

Output shows multiple thread ids. This means response packets are processed in parallel. Am I right? Two responses with thread id 9 return `null`. Is there any reason for it? I don't get it when working with synchronous model. Is this because `Thread.sleep` inside `ResponseListener`. So If I can't do blocking work inside `ResponseListener` and I want to process responses in parallel I need to add `ExecuterService`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SNMP4j uses Thread pools internally to process messages. The `ResponseListener`s's `onResponse()` is called from those threads, whose thread IDs you're seeing. Unlike in synchronous mode were it is executed in your own thread.

The `null` return value means it finished in timeout. And yes, I would guess it's because you're sleeping for 5 seconds in the `ResponseListener`, which blocks one of the message-receiving thread.

As for the `ExecutorService`, it would be a good idea to move the processing load out of SNMP4j message threads into your own code, where you can control the queue, etc. Alternatively you can use a synchronized `List` and a counting `Semaphore` that would wake up a thread to process the received messages.